# How to remove window.alert pop up?

Tags: javascript, mailto

Here is some script I copied to create a mailto link which grabs the browser URL and inserts it into the subject of the email. Its working perfect but every page I go to a Javascript alert box pops up saying:

mailto:address@address.ca?Subject="WHAT EVER IS IN THE BROWSER ADDRESS BAR"

Im rubbish with JS. How do I get the script to work without the alert pop up or even so with a lifespan?

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'>
</script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[ 
  $(window).load(function(){
  var url = "mailto:address@address.ca?Subject=" + window.location;
  $('#mailtoLink').attr('href', url);
  window.alert($('#mailtoLink').attr('href')); // = url;
  });//]]>

  </script>
```

HERE IS A EXAMPLE PAGE:

http://www.door9.co.uk/bex/his-thoughts/

Comment: Sometimes the answer is so easy, it is hard to see.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove this line `window.alert($('#mailtoLink').attr('href')); // = url;` so you're left with:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
var url = "mailto:address@address.ca?Subject=" + window.location;
$('#mailtoLink').attr('href', url);
});//]]>

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the window.alert function call.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.alert

Answer (score 1):

Take out this line; it was clearly for demo purposes only

```
window.alert($('#mailtoLink').attr('href')); // = url;
```